# $H^1$ convergence of eigenfunctions of Schrödinger operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convergence-divergence

Consider the Schrödinger-Operator with Potential $V\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions
$$ H^D=-\Delta + V $$
and let $u_{i,n}\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ be the first, nonnegative eigenfunctions to eigenvalues $\lambda_{i,n}$ of such an operator on their support. That is
$$ \int \nabla u_{i,n} \nabla\phi+ V u_{i,n} \phi - \lambda_{i,n} u_{i,n} \phi\, \mathrm dx =0  $$
for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\{u_i>0\})$.  In the following situation the $u_{i,n}$ converge against some $u_{i}$ in $H^1$. Furthermore the eigenvalues converge against $\mu_i$ .

Under which circumstances may I follow that $\mu_i$ is an eigenvalue on the support of $u_{i}$ with associated nonnegative eigenfunction $u_i$. This further implies that $\mu_i$ is indeed the first eigenvalue on $\{u_i >0\}$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is $V$ in fact $V_n$ ? Otherwise, there is exactly one positive eigenfunction (up to normalisation), and one corresponding eigenvalue. The sequence $u_{i,n}$ is in fact a constant sequence.

Comment: No, $V$ is always the same.  It is true that there is only one eigenfunction of the Schrödinger operator on $\Omega$ (up to normalisation).  But in this case, we define eigenfunctions on their support. Notice, this is important.  Eigenfunctions cannot vanish in any open subdomain they are defined (Cf. Reed-Simon IV Theorem XIII.57). I'm considering eigenfunction in the sense stated in the question.

Comment: The $u_{i,n}$ are in a sense minimizer of the spectral bound $\lambda_1(\{u_{i,n} >0\})$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me drop the index $i$.
Denote $\Omega_n=\{u_n>0\}$ and $\Omega_\infty=\{u>0\}$ where $u$ is the limit of the sequence $(u_n)$.
If you can establish the following lemma (which states that the domains $\Omega_n$ converge to $\Omega_\infty$ in some sense), then the claim is quite simple.
It suffices that $u_n\to u$ weakly.

**Lemma:**
For every compact $K\subset\Omega_\infty$ there is a natural number $N$ so that $K\subset\Omega_n$ for all $n>N$.

**Proof of the claim using the lemma:**
Take any $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega_\infty)$.
It follows from the lemma that $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega_n)$ for sufficiently large $n$.
If $u_n\to u$ weakly, then it follows from
$$
\int \nabla u_n \nabla\phi+ V u_n \phi - \lambda_n u_n \phi\, \mathrm dx =0
$$
that
\begin{eqnarray}
&&
\int \nabla u \nabla\phi+ V u \phi - \lambda u \phi\, \mathrm dx
\\&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \nabla u_n \nabla\phi+ V u_n \phi - \lambda u_n \phi\, \mathrm dx
\\&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \nabla u_n \nabla\phi+ V u_n \phi - \lambda_n u_n \phi\, \mathrm dx
+
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int (\lambda_n-\lambda) u_n \phi\, \mathrm dx
\\&=&
0.
\end{eqnarray}
To see that the second limit is zero, you can use the fact that weak convergence implies boundedness and estimate $\left|\int(\lambda_n-\lambda)u_n\phi\right|\leq |\lambda_n-\lambda|\|u_n\|_{L^2}\|\phi\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: I thought about this as well.  Would you suggest that the property stated in the lemma cannot be avoided?

Comment: I have pointwise convergence almost everywhere (that is the way I choose the $u_n$) but this doesn't imply your lemma I believe.

Comment: @Matthias, I don't see a way to avoid the lemma. From ae. pointwise convergence you get positivity of the limit and also uniform convergence outside arbitrarily small sets by Egorov's theorem. But I don't see how to turn these observations into the lemma yet. You will probably need regularity or boundary behaviour results for the eigenfunctions as well.

Comment: I added the reference and some details. I wonder if that might help

Comment: @Matthias, thanks. The paper looks relevant, but I don't have the time to study it and see if I could solve the problem that way. I would be delighted to know the answer, though.

Comment: I found after some discussion an answer to this problem. In fact, unfortunately my question was asked in a positive way.  But I'm kind of sure, that the supports have to converge in some sense as suggested by you.  I probably am going to change the question.  The discussion of the reason for its convergence in the given case involves some global discussion.